# How to add to stage four mathrandom answers from a bigger array of answers?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

How would I change the actionscript code to enable the quiz to present a random set of answers from a longer list? For example, could I have the quiz present just 4 random answers from an XML file containing 12 answers as flags in total?

I can get to put all of my 12 answers all the flags come out and in the question text field just one question witch is the name of one of those flags, but dont know how to randomly get just four of the flags and put them in the stage and one of the names in the text field

Xml example:

```
 <flags>
    <flag path="../assets/flags/flag1.png">                             
         <country>
            Aeland               
         </country>
    </flag> 

    <flag path="../assets/flags/AmSamoa.png">                               
         <country>
            AmSamoa          
         </country>
    </flag>  

    <flag path="../assets/flags/Bahamas.png">                               
         <country>
            Bahamas              
         </country>
    </flag>   
    <flag path="../assets/flags/CostaRica.png">                             
         <country>
            Costa Rica               
         </country>
    </flag>   
    <flag path="../assets/flags/CotedIvorie.png">                               
         <country>
            Cotedivoire          
         </country>
    </flag>   
    <flag path="../assets/flags/Croatia.png">                               
         <country>
            Croatia              
         </country>
    </flag>
```

And my AS3 code is:

```
private function onXMLLoad(event:Event):void
{           
    _xml = new XML(event.target.data); //create XML document_xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
    _myFlagList = new XMLList(_xml.flag);

    _xmlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    //  _xml.ignoreWhitespace = false;          
    // trace("MyFlag: _answers: ",_answers);          
    //trace(_loader);          
    //trace(targetBtn);
    //trace(_myFlagList);


    for each (var flagPath:XML in _xml.flag.@path) 
    {
        trace("MyFlag: flagaths: ",flagPath);
        _flagPaths.push(flagPath);
    }   


    for each (var flag:XML in _xml.flag.country)
    {       //trace("MyFlag: flagaths: ",flag);     
        _allFlags.push(flag);
    }

    createButtons();

}


private function onIOError(event:IOErrorEvent):void
{
    _xmlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onXMLLoad);
    _xmlLoader.removeEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR, onIOError);
    trace('IO Error:', event.text);

}

private function createButtons():void
{


    var col:int;
    var row:int;    
    flagContainer = new Sprite(); 


    trace("Number of flags",_allFlags.length);


    for (var i:int = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_BTNS; i++) 
    {
        _answers.push(_allFlags[i]);

        targetBtn = new FlagButton(_allFlags[i],_flagPaths[i]);             
        targetBtn.x = col * (targetBtn.width + 10)+20;
        targetBtn.y = row * (targetBtn.height+ 10)+20;
        flagContainer.addChild(targetBtn);
        addChild(flagContainer);



        col++;

        if( col == 3)
        {
            col = 0;
            row++;
        }
    }



    randomOption(); 
}
private function randomOption():void
{


    trace("MyFlag: all flags: ", _allFlags);        

    flagToFind = _allFlags[Math.floor(Math.random() * _allFlags.length)];
    trace("MyFlag: flag to find: ", flagToFind);        

    _bk.text.text=flagToFind;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically want an Array of Objects. Perhaps it will be better if you arrange your flags in XML as such:

```
<flag> 
     <path>../assets/flags/flag1.png</path> 
     <country>Aeland</country>
</flag>
```

With this, you will end up with an array of `flag` in your XML object, which can be iterated.

About selecting from an array at random - it's an easier task, just make sure you didn't select an index you've already selected previously.

```
var selected:Array=[];
while (selected.length<4) {
    var si:int=Math.floor(Math.random()*flags.length);
    if (selected.indexOf(si)==-1) selected.push(si);
}
trace(flags[selected[0]]); // first selected flag
trace(flags[selected[3]]); // fourth selected flag
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer, it helps alot, one more question, it gives me only two objects, but if i want to have four objects all the time? how do you do, at the same time i want to display them in a invosoble  button, thanks in advance for your time

Comment: Well, I've displayed how can you access a single object out of four selected, employ this technique to access all of them. About the button, you need to make four places in it so that each will accept an object of this kind, then either assign or `addChild()` or chenge text or whatever you see fit.